# SharePoint on prem lazy load some images

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

From one day to another SharePoint 2016 on prem suddenly lazy load some images. I don't know why and it doesen't work either - our images won't display. The image tags looks like this:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="/sites/test/_catalogs/theme/Themed/A99F70E7/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag%3d2"src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
```

If I replace src property with data-original url it works.

What happened? How do I turn this off?

Edit. I found this [lazy load plugin](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload) on our pages, still don't know where it come from or how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this has something to do with the Minimal Download Strategy-feature. If  activated, lazyload will *not* be in the DOM and everything works as expected, but only if I navigate using [site]**/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/** in the url. What this is all about... I don't know...

Comment: If you are not sure, put your thoughts as comments or put any reference link that can support your response